# Tkinter Scrollbars with Custom Class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a custom treeview class and am attempting to use scroll bars in conjunction with it.  The scroll bars appear above my treeview which is puzzling me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class myTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, *args):
        super().__init__()
        
        #parent widget, width and fields provided when object is created 

        self['show'] = 'headings'
        
        #create columns
        self['columns'] = args #args contains field names

        for column in args:
            self.column(column, anchor=CENTER, width=width)
            
        #and headings
        for column in args:
            self.heading(column, text=column, anchor=CENTER)
        
main = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(main)
frame1.pack()

test = myTree(frame1,100,'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')

#add vertical scroll bar
scrollbarV = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1,orient=VERTICAL, command=test.yview)
scrollbarV.pack(side='right', fill='y')
test.config(yscroll=scrollbarV.set)

#add horizontal scroll bar
scrollbarH = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1,orient=HORIZONTAL, command=test.xview)
scrollbarH.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
test.config(xscroll=scrollbarH.set)

test.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

If write the same code without the use of the custom class it works perfectly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Because the treeview is created as child of root window, not the frame.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you did not pass `parent` to `super().__init__()`, so the treeview is created as a child of the root window instead and packed below the frame.

```py
class myTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, *args):
        super().__init__(parent)  # passed parent
        ...
```

Also I would suggest to set `fill="both"` and `expand=1` to `test.pack()`.

Comment: Of course!  Many thanks.